# Reusing same view for several emails method with actiomailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_message_to_user(user, subject, body, locale)
    @body = body
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => subject)
  end

  def send_message_to_all_users(user, subject, body, locale)
    @body = body
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => subject)
  end

  def send_message_to_active_users(user, subject, body, locale)
    @body = body
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => subject)
  end

  def send_message_to_suspended_users(user, subject, body, locale)
    @body = body
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => subject)
  end
end
```

I would like instead use 4 views `send_message_to_active_users.html.erb`, `send_message_to_all_users.html.erb`, `send_message_to_suspended_users.html.erb`, `send_message_to_user.html.erb`, **for each action, I want use only 1 view file for all actions.**

**How can I do it?**

Thank  you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To choose another template, you can pass `:template_name` as an option:

```
mail(:to => user.email, :subject => subject, :template_name => "another_template_name")
```

So you can use one template for several methods.

Answer (score 0):

The response is:

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_message_to_user(user, subject, body, locale)
    @body = body
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => subject) do |format|
      format.html { render "send_email_to_users" }
    end
  end

  def send_message_to_all_users(user, subject, body, locale)
    @body = body
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => subject) do |format|
      format.html { render "send_email_to_users" }
    end
  end

  def send_message_to_active_users(user, subject, body, locale)
    @body = body
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => subject) do |format|
      format.html { render "send_email_to_users" }
    end
  end

  def send_message_to_suspended_users(user, subject, body, locale)
    @body = body
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => subject) do |format|
      format.html { render "send_email_to_users" }
    end
  end
end
```

You can take a look on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

Thank you!